# rabbitmq quorum Queue ensure retry if data is lost

Tags: rabbitmq, quorum

I read that Quorum Queue does not support ttl for both messages and Queues.

The producer in my system maintains state in database with message "READY_TO_SUBMIT" and then sends it to cluster of Quorum queue. In case the rabbitmq Queue crashes or for any reason the message is not delivered to consumer. How will my producer know that it should retry the message again.

In case of mirrored queue I assume I can put a ttl and then after the ttl gets over my producer can retry again if that status is not updated by consumer for "READY_TO_SUBMIT" to "SUBMITTED".

Answer (score 0):

Your producers absolutely must use publisher confirms correctly: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Please see the detailed tutorial here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-java.html

Comment: Publisher confirms guarantees that broker has received the message, how to reroute messages to a different exchange/queue if consumers of the queue are down?